# Implementing JQuery style 'deferred' and 'promise' in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, promise

I like the pattern of the jQuery [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) object.

I like how you can call `Resolve` any number of times, but the listening objects will only be notified once. I also like how you can attach a listening object after `Resolve` has already been called, and the listening object will still get the notification. If you're programming in an uncertain multithreaded environment, it greatly reduces the amount of thinking you have to do.

I couldn't find an equivalent in the C# library, so here is my implementation (a basic subset so far):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

interface IPromise
{
    void Done(Action action);
}

sealed class Deferred : IPromise
{
    readonly ConcurrentBag<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentBag<Action>();
    // using an int instead of a bool
    // so we can use Interlocked
    private int _isResolved = 0;

    internal void Resolve()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isResolved, 1);
        InvokeActions();
    }

    void IPromise.Done(Action action)
    {
        _actions.Add(action);
        if (_isResolved == 1)
        {
            InvokeActions();
        }
    }

    void InvokeActions()
    {
        Action action = null;
        while (_actions.TryTake(out action))
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

For this code to be usable, it has to be completely 100% thread safe. Can anyone see a hole in it?

Also, am I just re-implementing something that already exists in some corner of the .NET base class library?

For the sake of context I'll provide a practical use: there's a long running application, and some code that must execute if a file exists. The file might exist when the code first runs, or might come to exist later, or might never exist at all.
I invoke it like this:

```
 string fullPath = GenerateWatchedFilePath();
 FileSystemWatcherUtils
      .WhenFileAppears(fullPath)
         .Done(() =>
                {
                    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fullPath))
                    {
                       // etc
                    }
                }
              );
```

And my implementation of `WhenFileAppears`:

```
public static IPromise WhenFileAppears(string fullPath)
{
   Deferred returnPromise = new Deferred();
   if (File.Exists(fullPath))
   {
      returnPromise.Resolve();
      return returnPromise;
   }
   string subFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
   // This code assumes the subFolder exists
   // An exception will be thrown if it does not
   var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(subFolder);
   int onceOnlyFlag = 0;
   Action disposeOfWatcherAndResolve = () =>
   {
      if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref onceOnlyFlag, 1) == 0)
      {
          fileSystemWatcher.Dispose();
          returnPromise.Resolve();
      }
   };
   FileSystemEventHandler watcherHandler = (sender, args) =>
     {
        if (args.FullPath == fullPath)
        {
           disposeOfWatcherAndResolve();
        }
     };
   fileSystemWatcher.Created += watcherHandler;
   fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += (sender, args) => watcherHandler(sender, args);
   fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
   // Dealing with a race condition:
   // if the file came to exist between the last check
   // and the creation of the fileSystemWatcher
   if (File.Exists(fullPath))
   {
      disposeOfWatcherAndResolve();
   }
   return returnPromise;
}
```

Comment: I'm on a device so I won't go into detail, but I suggest looking at Reactive Extensions. They provide a powerful mechanism for synchronous or async data flow and are much more useful than Promises alone. In fact, there are ports for javascript because it's such a useful pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I like how you can call `Resolve` any number of times, but the listening objects will only be notified once. I also like how you can attach a listening object after `Resolve` has already been called, and the listening object will still get the notification. If you're programming in an uncertain multithreaded environment, it greatly reduces the amount of thinking you have to do.

This sounds a lot like `TaskCompletionSource` along with the `Task` it controls.

Assuming you have a `TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs`:

- To attach a listener, use `tcs.Task.ContinueWith(_ => /* listener code here */)`. You can do this before or after the `Task` has been completed and the listener code will be executed only once after the `Task` has been completed.
- To complete the `Task` (the equivalent of resolving), use `tcs.TrySetResult(someValue)`. If you'll use the `TrySetResult()` variant instead of `SetResult()`, the second and following attempt at completing will be ignored (`SetResult()` would throw an exception).

The difference with your code is that `TaskCompletionSource` always has some result type. You can either just ignore that (using e.g. `TaskCompletionSource<object>` and `SetResult(null)`), or use [the non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` from AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/TaskCompletionSource).

Answer (score 3):

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref _isResolved, 1);
```

`Interlocked.Exchange` is mostly useful because it returns the original value of the field in a thread-safe way. You don't use that, so a normal volatile write (change `_isResolved` to `volatile` and then use just `_isResolved = true;`)  would be enough here.

---

```
if (_isResolved == 1)
```

This is not thread-safe, the read needs to be volatile.

---

The way your code works, if you call `Resolve()` or `Done()` from multiple threads at the same time, the queued actions will be executed on multiple threads. And even if they were executed on a single thread, using `ConcurrentBag` means they will be executed in an unspecified order. Are you sure all that is okay?

---

The time it takes to call `Done()` and `Resolve()` can be very long and unpredictable (assuming you enqueued a long action before). Consider executing the actions on another thread (the thread pool is useful for that).